# Trying to return a object member for area but keep getting 0

Tags: c++, class, object, inheritance

I've been beating my head over this project and I can't figure out why this function will not return back the area of the polygon. I'm quite new to this so please don't be too rough on me. Here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Point
{
double xCoord, yCoord;
~Point(){};
};

class Triangle;

class Polygon
{
friend class Triangle;

private:
int totalVertices;
int lastIndex = 0;
double area = 0;

public:
void setNumOfVertices();
void setPoint(Point [], Point []);
int getNumOfVertices() const;
};


class Triangle : public Polygon
{
friend class Polygon;

private:
Point triangleVertices[2];
double triangleArea;

public:
double getArea(Point [], Point []);
};


void Polygon::setNumOfVertices()
{
    cout << "Please enter how many vertices(intersections) for this polygon: ";
    cin >> totalVertices;
    while (totalVertices < 3) {
        cout << "ERROR: Must have more than 2 vertices. Please try again." << endl;
        cout << "Please enter how many vertices(intersections) for this polygon: ";
        cin >> totalVertices;
    }
}

void Polygon::setPoint(Point points[2], Point vertexCoords[])
{
    for (int x = 1; x < totalVertices; x++) {
        if (x != lastIndex && x != 1) {
            points[0] = points[1];
            points[1] = vertexCoords[x];
            lastIndex = x;
            break;
        }
        else if (x == 1) {
            points[0] = vertexCoords[1];
            points[1] = vertexCoords[2];
            break;
        }
    }
}    


int Polygon::getNumOfVertices() const
{
    return totalVertices;
}

double Triangle::getArea(Point points[2], Point vertexCoords[])
{
    triangleArea = 0;
    triangleArea = ((vertexCoords[0].xCoord - points[2].xCoord) * (points[1].yCoord - vertexCoords[0].yCoord) -
               (vertexCoords[0].xCoord - points[1].xCoord) * (points[2].yCoord - vertexCoords[0].yCoord)) / 2;
    return triangleArea;
}



int main()
{
    Polygon polygon1;
    Triangle triangle1;
    double area = 0;
    polygon1.setNumOfVertices();
    Point vertexCoords[polygon1.getNumOfVertices()];
    Point trianglePts[2];

    //Get all vertex coordinates from user and store them in an array
    for (int x = 0; x < polygon1.getNumOfVertices(); x++) {
        cout << "Enter vertex number " << x + 1 << "'s X coordinate please: ";
        cin >> vertexCoords[x].xCoord;
        cout << "Enter vertex number " << x + 1 << "'s Y coordinate please: ";
        cin >> vertexCoords[x].yCoord;
    }
    cout << endl;

    //Output all vertex coordinates in parenthesis to the user via console
    cout << "The X and Y coordinates of the vertices are as follows:" << endl;
    for (int x = 0; x < polygon1.getNumOfVertices(); x++)
        cout << "(" << vertexCoords[x].xCoord << ", " << vertexCoords[x].yCoord <<
            ")" << endl;

    for (int x = 0; x < polygon1.getNumOfVertices(); x++) {
        polygon1.setPoint(trianglePts, vertexCoords);
        area += triangle1.getArea(trianglePts, vertexCoords);
    }

    //Output the area of the polygon
    cout << endl;
    cout << "The area of the polygon is: " << area << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

When I call the getArea(Point[], Point[]) function in my loop to get the area in my main function, it seems as if the member variable triangleArea of the class Triangle never gets updated as it should. Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong? Everything else works like a charm I just get 0 for my area everytime I run the program. Thank you for your time.

Comment: If you had read the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking, you would know not to post a huge blob of code, but an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) instead.

Comment: I took out what didn't need to be there now. Sorry.

Comment: Still too much superfluous code, and besides, it needs proper formatting. BTW: What does your first comment *mean*?

Comment: Every `Point::xCoord` and `Point::yCoord` is probably `0.0`.   I don't see code that sets them to anything else.

Comment: I was just trying to point out where the problem was. I figured you would need to see all of that code to see where the problem was. I'm not used to formatting code on this site. Let me fix it.

Comment: The points are set by the user, and when I debug and check the watch list I can see that they are all set to the user inputs.

Comment: Essentially my question is, why is that member variable triangleArea of the class Triangle not being changed in the function getArea()? Is it in my math logic? or is it in improper code?

Comment: You are correctly assigning to `triangleArea` in that function.  Twice for some reason.  If `0.0` is the value being assigned and you don't know why, provide a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) here and it will be possible for us to do more than guess.

Comment: @DrewDormann I updated my post with a working shortened version of my code. This should show that when the getArea() function is called the points have values other than 0,0 at least from what I can see. Like I said, I am new to this.

Answer (score 0):

You continually access out of bounds of these Point arrays. For example, in `Triangle::getArea` the parameter is:

```
Point points[2];
```

but you access `points[1]` and `points[2]`. Arrays have 0-based indices.

At first glance I thought that `trianglePts` and `triangleVertices` had the wrong size, since you gave them size `[2]` and triangles actually have `3` vertices. However I now think that what you are trying to do is only store two of the 3 vertices of each triangle in the calculation in this array, and always use `vertexCoords[0]` as the third vertex.

This is confusing to say the least.

The design and logic of `Triangle::getArea()` is wrong too. Firstly it doesn't even use any member variables of the `Triangle` class , which is a bad sign. Instead, this should be a non-member function and it only needs to take 3 points as argument (be it an array of 3, or an array of 2 plus a third one as separate argument). You don't need the `Triangle` class at all, and you don't need to pass the entire `vertexCoords` array.

Next: `Polygon::setPoint` is a mess. I *think* what you are trying to do is actually *get* the next pair of 2 points out of `vertexCoords`. Again, this does not use any member variables of `Polygon` so it does not make sense to have it be a member function.   Well , it does use `lastIndex` but that's a bad idea. You're using `lastIndex` to shuffle along the points you got last time but this is a fragile and confusing design.

Also this function doesn't even work: every time you call it just executes the same `else if (x == 1)` branch because the first `if` is never true before that!

It would be much simpler to just have the function give the required 3 points where you pass in the `Index` as a parameter. Maybe call it `get3Points` instead of `setPoint`.

What you should really be doing is having the `Polygon` store the list of vertex coordinates as a member variable, instead of passing it into every function. 
(This means you will have to use a `vector` as a member variable to hold them).

If you don't want to do this then there's not even any point having the `Polygon` class at all, you could just make `get3Points` a free function that you pass `vertexCoords` to each time.

Another issue is that the final loop executes too many times. If there are a total of `3` vertices this loop should run once, but you actually run it `3` times (and in doing so, `setPoint` reads off the end of `vertexCoords` -- or it would if `setPoint` wasn't broken to only ever read points 1 and 2).